# How to pass extra parameter to purrr::map with dplyr pipe

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have the following data frame and function:

```r
param_df <- data.frame(
  x = 1:3 + 0.1,
  y = 3:1 - 0.2
)


param_df
#>     x   y
#> 1 1.1 2.8
#> 2 2.1 1.8
#> 3 3.1 0.8

my_function <- function(x, y, z) {
  x + y + z
}
```

What I want to do is to pass `param_df` to `my_function` function but with extra parameters which don't contain in `param_df`, say `z=3`.

I tried this but failed:

```r
library(tidyverse)
param_df %>% 
  purrr::map(my_function, z =3 )
```

> ```r
> Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : argument "y" is missing, with no default
> ```

The expected result is a list with three values, all: `6.9`.

I know I can insert `3` in `param_df` as extra column `z`.
But that's not I want. Because in reality, the function and `z` 
perform more complex calculation.

How can I go about it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

param_df <- data.frame(
  x = 1:3 + 0.1,
  y = 3:1 - 0.2
)

my_function <- function(x, y, z) {
  x + y + z
}

param_df %>% pmap(~my_function(.x,.y,3))

# [[1]]
# [1] 6.9
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 6.9
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 6.9
```

Another solution could be:

```
map2(param_df$x, param_df$y, ~my_function(.x,.y,3))
```

Comment: thanks. `.x` and `.y` refers to the `param_df` or `function` ?

Comment: Those refer to the data you want to pass to your function via `map`. So, `.x` is the 1st parameter you provide (i.e. `param_df$x`) and `.y` is the 2nd one (i.e. `param_df$y`)

Comment: thanks. Can it be named as other? e.g. `param_df %>% pmap(~my_function(.Var1,.Var2,3))`

Comment: That's `pmap`'s way to understand what input you want to pass. You can do something like that if you use a process like this `param_df %>% 
  group_by(id = row_number()) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(d = map_dbl(data, ~my_function(.x$x, .x$y, 3)))`. Now `.x$x` means column `x` from `data` and `.x$y` means column `y` from `data`.