# Translating a 'for loop' to 'purrr::map'

Tags: r, purrr

I am trying to translate this basic for loop using the purr package. The idea is to apply a function using data frame elements as parameters.

Creating the data frame to loop on using the `mpg` dataset from `ggplot2`:

```
param <- mpg %>% select(manufacturer, year) %>% distinct() %>% rename(man = manufacturer, y = year)
```

The function to apply:

```
fcn <- function(man, y) {
    df <- mpg %>% filter(manufacturer == man & year == y)
    mod <- lm(data = df, cty ~ hwy)
    out <- summary(mod)
    return(out)
}
```

And the loop to apply `fcn` for each `man` and `y` combination :

```
for (i in 1:nrow(param)) {
    fcn(man = param$man[i], 
        y = param$y[i])
}
```

I am very new to purr and struggle how general specifications of purr::map work. 
Thanks a lot.

EDIT : 
I used here a very basic example with `fcn` and `param` to understand how to include function parameters (from `param`) inside the map specification. As a results, I was not particularly interested in a nesting beforehand but only the dull translation of the loop using map that could work for any king of function with multiple parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following post helped me to achieve the desired outcome, general enough to be applied in many situations and ignoring nesting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52309113/10580543.

Using pmap:

```
output <- param %>% pmap(~fcn(.x, .y))
```

Answer (score 2):

If I have understood correctly you want to model the `cty` based on `hwy` for each `year` and `manufacturer` combinations.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(purrr)
```

I have changed the definition of your function to fit to the `map` function settings.

```
fcn <- function(df){
  mod <- lm(data = df, cty ~ hwy)
  return(summary(mod))
}
```

The code below should produce the summary of the model for each year and manufacturer

```
mpg %>% group_by(manufacturer, year) %>%
  nest() %>% mutate(model = map(data, fcn))
```

Comment: RStudio's purrr cheatsheet is a very concise but helpful resource.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I posted an alternative only for the translation of the loop into purr.

Answer (score 1):

You can nest the data first within manufacturer and year, then map using a function, except below, I used the `.x` directly, which would be each element of the data you map through. You can also use `tidy()` from broom to put the `summary()` result into a data.frame:

```
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(broom)

mpg = ggplot2::mpg

result = mpg %>% 
select(manufacturer, year,cty,hwy) %>% 
nest(data=c(cty, hwy)) %>% 
mutate(
model=map(data,~lm(cty ~ hwy,data=.x)),
summary=map(model,~tidy(summary(.x)))
) 

# A tibble: 30 x 5
   manufacturer  year data              model  summary         
   <chr>        <int> <list>            <list> <list>          
 1 audi          1999 <tibble [9 × 2]>  <lm>   <tibble [2 × 5]>
 2 audi          2008 <tibble [9 × 2]>  <lm>   <tibble [2 × 5]>
 3 chevrolet     2008 <tibble [12 × 2]> <lm>   <tibble [2 × 5]>
 4 chevrolet     1999 <tibble [7 × 2]>  <lm>   <tibble [2 × 5]>
 5 dodge         1999 <tibble [16 × 2]> <lm>   <tibble [2 × 5]>
 6 dodge         2008 <tibble [21 × 2]> <lm>   <tibble [2 × 5]>
```

If you want to look at the results of summary:

```
 result %>% unnest(summary)
# A tibble: 55 x 9
   manufacturer  year data    model  term   estimate std.error statistic p.value
   <chr>        <int> <list>  <list> <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 audi          1999 <tibbl… <lm>   (Inte…   -5.85     6.15      -0.951 3.73e-1
 2 audi          1999 <tibbl… <lm>   hwy       0.879    0.235      3.74  7.27e-3
 3 audi          2008 <tibbl… <lm>   (Inte…   -0.5      3.68      -0.136 8.96e-1
 4 audi          2008 <tibbl… <lm>   hwy       0.695    0.137      5.08  1.43e-3
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edited the post to mention I was looking for something very general to help me understand the correct specification of purr for functions with multiple parameters.